# Surrounded region algorithm

Tags: algorithm

The "Surrounded Region" problem states:

"Given a 2D board containing 'X' and 'O', capture all regions surrounded by 'X'.
A region is captured by flipping all 'O's into 'X's in that surrounded region."

**I'm confused as to what the task is for this problem. I'm not clear on what dictates when a region is *'surrounded'* based on all the examples found online(which happen to all be the same example).**

**The example given.**

```
input                               output

X X X X                            X X X X
X O O X                            X X X X
X X O X                            X X X X
X O X X                            X O X X
```

Both groups of O's look surrounded by X's to me. Is the rule that all four sides need to be surrounded by X's? and since the bottom O doesn't have a X below it it's not *'captured'*?

what happens if this is the input? is nothing *captured* at all?

```
X X X X                            
X O O O                           
X X O X                           
X O X X
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition, if 'O' cell is surrounded by 'X' cells, i.e. up/down/left/right cells are 'X'.
The first thought could be for each 'O' cell, add it to an array, check its up/down/left/right and if it is another 'O' cell, continue until, it hits all 'X' cells or it hits boundary. In the former case, cells in the array can all be flipped to'X'; while in the latter case, cells in the array cannot be flipped.

Comment: Notice that any 'O' cells that connected (directly or indirectly) to a boundary 'O' cell can not be flipped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly. 

This surrounding and capturing is in fact, like a game (of `GO`). The edges cannot be captured, that's it. If you put your dots to edges, they will be yours till the end of the game. Also, surrounding means, `if O's are surrounded by X's, then X's will form a cycle around O's. And whenever such a cycle completes, all the inside O's will be flipped to X's and vice-versa`.

**definition of cycle:**

A cycle of X's or O's is any connected region where you start from a cell and return to it, without repeating (revisiting) a cell, and each step you can take a `chess piece king's` move to complete the path.
So, in your input example, the path:
(1,0)->(0,1)->(0,2)->(1,3)->(2,3)->(3,2)->(2,1)->(1,0) forms a cycle.

Comment: In the game of go, the stone in the edge can be captured by filling the adjacent points. in other words, the outside of the board is always treated as opponents stone, so in this case, the `O` can be captured by `X` if this is game of go.

Comment: This is *like* the game of GO. In GO, we actually capture `lines`(1-D). Extend it to 2-D and you will get this game. This is the reason why in GO, you can't capture corners and in this game, you can't capture edges.

Comment: I don't think giving the game of go as example is appropriate here since game of go has three state, `empty`, `black`, `white`. The problem only has two state `O` and `X`.

Comment: Actually I have worked on this (2-D GO game or whatever, I never knew what its actual name is). The game I created started with an empty grid of course, and in each turn, you would put your dots to create a cycle. For every cycle you complete, all the inner points will be captured (be they empty or of opponent).

Comment: But in this example a circle isn't made around the top group of O's if you look at the southwest diagonal there is  a O there and not an X. so its not completely surrounded at least not on all 8 sides. If only 4 sides are required to be surrounded (north, south, east, west) then that would make more sense with this example

Comment: So, this problem had a similar description and I related it to GO (because I didn't and still don't know the name of 2-D version). I see much similarity. This is just a state of the board at any time (may be state of a sub-matrix of the board).

Comment: @MarquisBlount, I'll edit my answer for the definition of cycle. A cycle does not mean completing a rectangle or a circle around.